# People inside a Wordsquare

Tags: knowledge, word-square

Hold on, it's not a riddle! This time, you must fill in a 4×4 Wordsquare. Sounds easy, right? But now, they are not English words. They're *names*!

1. Mia + Bareilles + Gilbert + Arjun
2. Cummings + Walker + Rickman + Alda
3. Brooks + al'Thor + Danny + Wilson
4. Garcia + Whitfield + Dick + Serkis

16 names for 16 squares. Fair enough, isn't it? But, as the rules of Wordsquares say, fill each square with *one* letter only. But *how*? Figure it out yourself!

Comment: This is a 30-second Google solve (or fewer if you already know some). I would suggest not using as many examples and/or not stating outright that we need names. In the future, try introducing some additional complexity -- one way is with obfuscation -- perhaps writing a line of text for each row and hiding the names within?

Comment: @feelinferrety Oops, I never realized that it can be googled. I will certainly make harder puzzles next time. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wordsquare:

> S A R A
>  A L A N
>  R A N D
>  A N D Y
>  
>  The first or second names of quite famous real or fictional characters.
>  
>  Sara Mia, Sara Bareilles, Sara Gilbert, Sara Arjun
>  Alan Cummings, Alan Walker, Alan Rickman, Alan Alda
>  Rand Brooks, Rand al'Thor, Danny Rand, Rand Wilson
>  Andy Garcia, Andy Whitfield, Andy Dick, Andy Serkis